# Adding line break after header only in 2nd Page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I want to add line break only in 2nd page.
Here is generated pdf link
https://www.docdroid.net/pjvfJPn/10020.pdf.html. Here is my code In CodeIgniter

```
$this->load->library('m_pdf');

$pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
$pdf2 = $this->m_pdf->load();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$data['total_page_number'] = $pdf->page;
$pdf->DeletePages();

$pdfFilePath = FCPATH."pdf/" . $file_name;
$returnPath = "pdf/" . $file_name;
$html2 = $this->load->view('projects/pdf/projects_pdf', $data, true);
$footer_html = dashboard_lang('_CONTRACT_PDF_END_TEXT');
$header_html = $this->load->view('projects/pdf/header_text', $data, true);

$pdf2->SetHTMLHeader( $header_html );
$pdf2->setHTMLFooter($footer_html);
$pdf2->AddPage('', '', '', '', '', 15, // left
3, // right
48, // top
16, // bottom
5, 2); // footer bottom


if ($download_pdf) {

    $pdf2->WriteHTML($html2);
    $pdf2->Output('' . $file_name, 'D');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is the way by which you can add a break in line.

```
 $pdf->InsertText('Rakesh\n\nKumar');
```

Try With this . Thanks